# DKIM for private Gmail users

Tags: gmail

I have a private Gmail account (without GSuite or Google Apps) and would like to send as an email I bought with a domain. However, a question mark appears next to my name when I send emails like this. Can I set up DKIM for this scenario? I've googled extensively but all I can find are answers for their business solutions

Answer (score -1):

You won't be able to add DKIM for a private domain without paying Google, but make sure your SPF TXT records are right: it should be "v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all".